# Proving a list spans a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

This is more of a general question regarding all proofs of similar type however here is a particular example:

[image]

I understand I that to prove said list to be a basis, I need to show that it is linearly independent and spans V. I am perfectly fine with the proving LI portion however I have a question about proving that it spans V.

Here is a proof I found online regarding the span part of the proof:
[image]

My proof summarized: (The first part is basically the same as the online one)Because $V=U⊕W$, for any $v ∈ V$, we have: $v=u+w$ for some $u ∈ U$ and $w ∈ W$. Let a $a_1,...,a_m,c_1,...,c_n ∈ F$ such that: $u = a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m$ and $w=c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n$. Thus we have $v = a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m+c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n ∈ span(u_1+...+u_m,w_1,...,w_n)$ for any $v ∈ V$. Therefore $V ⊆ span(u_1+...+u_m,w_1,...,w_n)$.

This is where the online proof ends however I use double inclusion to prove it.

Cont. Proof: For any $v ∈ span(u_1+...+u_m,w_1,...,w_n)$, there must exist some scalars $a_1,...,a_m,c_1,...,c_n ∈ F$ such that $v = a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m+c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n$. Because there is some $u ∈ U$ with $u=a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m ∈ U$ and some $w ∈ W$ with $w = c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n$, we have $v=u+w ∈ U+W = V$ for any $v$. Therefore $span(u_1+...+u_m,w_1,...,w_n) ⊆ V$.

Therefore, $span(u_1+...+u_m,w_1,...,w_n) = V$
(Any feedback on the proof is appreciated)

My question: I'm new to proofs so I'm not sure if my proof is completely correct and/or if I am doing too much as I seem to have an extra part. If I only had the first part (as the online proof did) would that be adequate? Or is the "second" part not shown as it is considered "obvious".

Comment: Yeah it's correct.

Comment: @Seeker For the second part of my question, if I only had the first part of the proof, would it be enough?

Comment: You are essentially writing the same thing again. I get where you are coming from. But consider this: In the first part you showed that every vector $v\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of $u_1,. . .u_m,w_1,. . .,w_n$. This alone proves that span$(u_1,. . .,u_m,w_1,. . .,w_n)=V$. You are just rewriting that again in the second part of your proof. Although it is not wrong, it's just redundant. But your proof is completely correct!

Comment: To answer the question. Yes, the first part of your proof suffices!

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing up my confusion. I was thinking the same thing but I wasn't sure. I felt like I was just writing the same thing in reverse for the second part.

Comment: @Seeker If you want you can leave your comments as an answer

Comment: It's all good. Glad I could help!

Comment: I’ve just wanted to update my original answer to your question. The standard way to show that a set A = B is to show that A $\subset$ B and B $\subset$ A. Your original proof is also correct and most people would accept that as a correct proof. So, in the future try proving two sets are equal in that way.